# TSQL custom rounding

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, t-sql, rounding

I'm using *SQL-Server 2008 R2*.

I need to achieve following rounding. If first digit after decimal point is 0 It should round to lower side, if higher or equal to 1, should round to higher side, sample data:

```
3.09   ---> 3
3.1    ---> 4
0      ---> 0
3.005  ---> 3
668.15 ---> 669
```

What would be simplest way to achieve It?

I've tried to do something like that:

```
SELECT CEILING(3.09) -- this is incorrect, returning 4 instead of 3
SELECT ROUND(3.09,0) -- with 3.09 is ok, but if I'm trying to round 3.1 It still returning 3.00 instead of 4
```

Maybe somehow could I combine It? Or I need any other function?

Comment: What do _higher_ and _lower_ mean with respect to negative values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT ROUND(val + 0.4, 0) rnd_val
FROM (
    VALUES 
    (3.09),
    (3.1  ),
    (0),
    (3.005),
    (668.15)
)v (val)
```

[image]

Comment: Simply Brilliant!